# Why do I see duplicate API Call when using Python requests library deployed on container, one from container IP and one from Host IP?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, python-requests, mockoon

I have a python application deployed in docker container. For each request I sent to the external API server (rest api), I can see two HTTP requests on tcpdump; one from container IP, another from host IP.

I tried to check if the program is triggering 2 requests, but only 1 is found in logs and for every trigger request is logged

With tcp dump capture
`tcpdump -i any -nn host 10.222.xx.yy`
[image]

With Mockoon attachment:
[image]

**Logs where API is invoked:**

2023-02-21 10:05:43,442 DEBUG    app.processors.outgoing Process Messages ...
2023-02-21 10:05:43,449 INFO     app.processors.outgoing Sending message to consumer with Id: 1 => Trans Id: 1676963144066_3084018310_3084018310
2023-02-21 10:05:43,452 DEBUG    app.processors.outgoing 1 =>Timeout: 5.0
2023-02-21 10:05:43,454 DEBUG    urllib3.connectionpool Starting new HTTP connection (1): 10.222.yyy.xxx:9001
2023-02-21 10:05:43,490 DEBUG    urllib3.connectionpool http://10.222.^^^.^^^:9001 "POST /rtt/notify HTTP/1.1" 200 2
2023-02-21 10:05:43,494 DEBUG    urllib3.connectionpool Starting new HTTP connection (1): 10.222.^^^.^^^:9001
2023-02-21 10:05:43,543 DEBUG    urllib3.connectionpool http://10.222.^^^.^^^:9001 "POST /rtt/notify HTTP/1.1" 200 2
2023-02-21 10:05:43,544 DEBUG    app.processors.outgoing Latency(ms): 50.673
2023-02-21 10:05:43,545 INFO     app.processors.outgoing Success Response: 200, {}
2023-02-21 10:05:43,573 DEBUG    app.common.decorators Timer: app.processors.outgoing: send_message_to_consumer took 123.77ms: Args: ()
2023-02-21 10:05:43,574 INFO     app.processors.outgoing Processed 1 messages
2023-02-21 10:05:43,574 DEBUG    app.common.decorators Timer: app.processors.outgoing: process_out_messages took 132.18ms: Args: ()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us how you're running `tcpdump`, but I suspect that rather than seeing multiple requests, you're seeing the same request as it gets routed through your host.

If on my host I run:

```bash
tcpdump -i any -nn host stackoverflow.com
```

And then I spin up a container and run `curl stackoverflow.com`, I will see *three* results for every packet in the exchange (note that I've performed some manual alignment here to make things a bit easier to read):

```
07:25:32.969736 veth7b48792 P   IP 172.17.0.2.33710    > 151.101.1.69.80: ...
07:25:32.969741 docker0     In  IP 172.17.0.2.33710    > 151.101.1.69.80: ...
07:25:32.969747 eth0        Out IP 192.168.1.200.33710 > 151.101.1.69.80: ...
                 ^
                 |
                 +-- this column is the interface name
```

The first result shows the packet exiting the container (recall that a `veth` virtual wire connects `eth0` inside the container to a device -- in this case `veth8b48792` -- on the host, which is what gets added to the docker bridge).

The second result shows the packet traversing the docker bridge.

The third result shows the packet leaving the host's primary interface (after address translation in the `nat` table).

If you limit `tcpdump` to a single interface, you should only see a single match for each packet in the request. E.g., if I were to run `tcpdump -i eth0 -nn host stackoverflow.com`, I would see only:

```
07:46:33.505078 IP 192.168.1.200.50194 > 151.101.65.69.80: ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much @larsks for prompt answer. Will check and feedback. Though on redhat 8, tcpdump does not show the interfaces of each captured packet

``

Comment: Right, you may need a more recent tcpdump for that (I think this feature comes with 4.99.x).

Comment: Thanks for advise, I will update the TCP dump. I have tried with a mock api service mockoon and getting double request for one trigger.

Comment: Hello @larsks, thanks so much for pointing to the behavior of docker vs host requests handling/transition. That is confirmed to be the case, and helped me to focus on checking other causes, and it turned out that i had a bug in my code, sending twice for the same request.